# Won't set cookie on localhost?

Tags: php, cookies

Hello im trying to create a cookie on localhost

This is my code:

```
<?php
      SESSION_START();
      if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        $available_langs = array("se", "uk");
        if (in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs)) {
          setcookie("wb_lang", $_GET['lang'], "1", "/", "localhost");
        }
        else {

          $_SESSION['sess_error'] = LANGUAGE_YOU_SELECTED_DOESNT_EXIST;
        }
        header("Location: /");
        exit;
      }
?>
```

That part set the cookie, if i take die after the cookie is set i get the an answer from the cookie.

But when i try to use the cookie on index.php, it doesn't exist at all..

The language.php is in a subfolder named /modules/language.php it that is any problem?

So the cookie is set, but only in language.php and i can't seem to find any answer for this either, i tried several answers without any success.

Comment: Sidenote: You realize that `LANGUAGE_YOU_SELECTED_DOESNT_EXIST` is treated as  constant. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set your `$expire` (third) argument to `"1"`, which is always in the past, so the cookie will always instantly expire.

If this is a session cookie, you can use `0`.

If you want it to persist when the browser closes and reopens, you will need to set a value in the future, e.g. `time() + 365*24*60*60` for the cookie to survive approximately 1 year.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Even if i dont set or set the time it still doesn't exist

Comment: setcookie("cookie", "time() + 365*24*60*60", "/", "localhost")
setcookie("cookie", "", "/")
setcookie("cookie", "time() + 365*24*60*60")

Thats some of them, but if i put it in the index.php it sets like it should :S

Comment: Ah right.  You're passing it in as a string, so you're literally passing the value `"time() + 365*24*60*60"`.  Take out the quotes `"` and it will evaluate the expression and give a number result, which is what you want:
`setcookie("cookie", "value", time() + 365*24*60*60, ...)`